# How can I make this code work while keeping the numbers inside the function?

Tags: python

I want the function do most of the work, due to the requirements of the project

```
def tax(choice):
    a = 1.4
    b = 2.2
    print(choice * 1.12)

print("What will you buy?")
print("[a] Salt - $1.40")
print("[b] Pepper -$2.20")
choice = input()

print("It will cost ${}".format(tax(choice)))
```

I have tried everything to my knowledge (which isn't a lot)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary to get the choice from the (`string`) input:

```
def tax(choice):                                                                                                      
    choices = {"a" : 1.4, "b" : 2.2}                                                                                  
    return choices[choice] * 1.12                                                                                     
                                                                                                                      
print("What will you buy?")                                                                                           
print("[a] Salt - $1.40")                                                                                             
print("[b] Pepper -$2.20")                                                                                            
choice = input()                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                      
print("It will cost {}".format(tax(choice)))
```

You may want to use f-strings too, as this is the modern way to print messages containing variables:

```
print(f"It will cost {tax(choice)}.")
```

(note the `f` at the beginning)